# Loading Another XAML on Image Tap

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I'm new to Windows 8 App Development. I have a Main.xaml and has an Image on it with
Image on Tap event. I used VB.

How can I load another xaml if the Image on Main.xaml is tapped? Ex. I want to load Second.xaml.

Thanks. I use Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to Windows 8 App Dev, you first need to take a look at [the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229566.aspx) and to answer your question the [navigation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh757631.aspx) documentation.